MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method canStartScan on channel wifi_scan)-I'm receiving this error in my flutter app
MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method canStartScan on channel wifi_scan)-I'm receiving this error for a method in wifi_scan package in my flutter app. But my flutter code was working fine with the same package earlier. I did not make any changes relating to the package or the method. I even reverted all the changes i had made, but the code still throws this error. Any idea on what might be the issue here?

scanNspeakwifi() async{      
      resultcanstarscan = await WiFiScan.instance.canStartScan();  /* This is the line where the exception occurs*/
      // print("passed canstartscan : $resultcanstarscan");
      if(resultcanstarscan == CanStartScan.yes){
        scansuccess = await WiFiScan.instance.startScan();
        // print("scan success: $scansuccess");
        notification('Scanning in progress', Colors.yellow);
      }
      else {
        notification('Cannot start scan. Check if location permissions are given!', Colors.red);
      }

          cangetresults = await WiFiScan.instance.canGetScannedResults();
          // print("Passed cangetresults $cangetresults");
          if(cangetresults == CanGetScannedResults.yes ){
            scanresults = await WiFiScan.instance.getScannedResults();
             notification('Scan completed! Click on "Get Results" to view nearby Nspeak device', Colors.green);
          }
          else {
            notification('No scan result available. Check if location permissions are given!', Colors.red);
      }
  
    }

I have already tried uninstalling the package, reinstalling it, tried flutter clean.  I tried reverting all the changes I have made. But no luck.
